# iptables blocking incoming traffic for the network

Tags: iptables

Which rule can be applied through iptables deny incoming traffic sent to IP address 1.1.1.1?

For example - iptables -P INPUT DROP - blocks all traffic, but I only need to block traffic for a specific IP address since I have 2 IP addresses.

On a different interface. The main one on eth0, and which one needs to be blocked on eth2

Tries different options but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth2 -s 1.1.1.1 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks! what does 1 mean?

Comment: This rule becomes first in the INPUT chain

Answer (score 0):

Inserts a rule at the top of the INPUT chain that blocks all traffic from 1.1.1.1 on eth2